# Restart a Running Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, gtk#

I'm new to threading and need a lot of help.
I have code based on events that starts a thread. The problem is that I loose references to the thread and thread.abort(); does not stop it, therefore my application doesn't stop. Thanks

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Threading;

public class Trackbox {
public static Thread thread;
public static void Main() {
    Application.Init();

    //Create the Window
    Window myWin = new Window("Trackbox");
    myWin.SetIconFromFile("Assets//logo.png");
    myWin.Resize(200, 100);


    Button playButton = new Button("Play Sound");
    playButton.Clicked += new EventHandler(playWav);
    myWin.Add(playButton);

    myWin.DeleteEvent += delegate { exitTrackbox(); };
    //Show Everything     
    myWin.ShowAll();


    Application.Run();


}

private static void exitTrackbox() {
    //Doesn't kill the application
    thread.Abort();
    Application.Quit();
}

private static void playWav(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Reference to Thread
    thread = new Thread(playWavThread);
    thread.Start();
}

private static void playWavThread()
{
    var soundFile = @"C:\sound.wav";
    using (var wfr = new WaveFileReader(soundFile))
    using (WaveChannel32 wc = new WaveChannel32(wfr) { PadWithZeroes = false })
    using (var audioOutput = new WaveOut())
    {
        audioOutput.Init(wc);
        audioOutput.Play();
        while (audioOutput.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        audioOutput.Stop();
    }

}
}
```

Please give any advice you have about this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without going too deep into threading and how to use threads and whatnot (I suggest reading more on threading in C# and then attempting again - the book CLR via C# has a great deal on threading, and of course there's many sites on the internet), to get your application to die in this case, you should probably set your thread as a background thread:

```
private static void playWav(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Reference to Thread
    thread = new Thread(playWavThread);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

Non-background threads keep your application from terminating, but background threads happily die on process shutdown.  For any thread that isn't critical to the application being run, you should set it as a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Could you please explain why background thread makes a difference?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx : A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Also, depending on the end goal, you might look into using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead.  It seems like it provides the functionality that you need with the ability to implement cancellation of the thread.  Also, the benefit of doing it this way is it will be faster to use a BackgroundWorker since they use threads from the thread pool.  The downside is that there are a limited number available, so if you are using a lot of them, they can fight each other for the available thread pool threads.